# How to show single array only?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm making a recommendation system and I want to show only the top 1 from the recommendation instead of all of it.
    this is the code

```
$movies = mysqli_query($db, "select * from practice");

while ($movie=mysqli_fetch_array($movies))
{
    $users=mysqli_query($db,"select username from users where id =$movie[user_id]");
    $username=mysqli_fetch_array($users);

    $matrix[$username['username']] [$movie['image']] = $movie ['ratings'];
}


$users=mysqli_query($db,"select username from users where id=$_GET[id]");
$username=mysqli_fetch_array($users);
?>
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>
                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="index.php"> Back </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <th>Clothes</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
<?php 
    $recommendation=array();

    $recommendation = getRecommendation($matrix,$username['username']);
    foreach($recommendation as $movie => $rating) {
?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo "<img src='images/".$movie."' >"; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $rating  ; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: use `break` at the end of the loop

Comment: Use `LIMIT 1` in the query

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `LIMIT` in your sql query.

> ## LIMIT Query
>
> If you need only a specified number of rows from a result set, use a LIMIT clause in the >query, rather than fetching the whole result set and throwing away the extra data.
>
> MySQL sometimes optimizes a query that has a LIMIT row_count clause and no HAVING clause

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY category;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | category | rating |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |    4.5 |
|  5 |        1 |    3.2 |
|  3 |        2 |    3.7 |
|  4 |        2 |    3.5 |
|  6 |        2 |    3.5 |
|  2 |        3 |    5.0 |
|  7 |        3 |    2.7 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY category LIMIT 1;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | category | rating |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |    4.5 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html